# Is it ok to run python file, edit it, then run it in second terminal

Tags: python, gem5

I'm running a simulation (more on this in a sec) and one of the files for this simulation is a python file that contains configuration details. I want to run multiple versions of this simulation, but I don't know if running one simulation, opening another terminal, then editing the python file and running a second simulation will ruin the first simulation. Does python have a concept of "source code" is separate from the actual process? Can I edit the file safely? These simulations take a while.

(So, I'm running a gem5 simulation and I need to run multiple versions of the simulation, varying properties of the CPU. Just in case that helps.)

Comment: One situation in which this approach may fail is when downstream code calls `reload` on your config module.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the first instance it will use the first Python config file. Then when you run the second instance it will run the newly updated config file. It should all work fine as long as its not running on a localhost port, because it will try to use the same port and wont run. If this is not the case then it should run with the updated config file.

Comment: And `fs.py` at least test if ports are used and then goes for the next one, so it should work fine there.